# Comparing differences (error) between two tables in SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, delta

I want to calculate a delta between the rows of two tables with the exact same structure, but not necessarily the same data.

table 1 (predictions)

> Id     |     Name |  GP | G | A

table 1 (actual data)

> Id     |     Name |  GP | G | A

result (matched by Id):

> Id     | (GP1-GP2) AS DeltaGP | (G1-G2) AS DeltaG | (A1-A2) AS DeltaA |

Catch my drift? This is to caclulate the error of a prediction model in SSAS

Here is my code:

```
    SELECT P.[Player_id]
          ,P.[PlayerName]
          ,sum(P.[Games Played])-sum(S.[GamesPlayed]) AS GP
          ,sum(P.[Total Goals])-sum(s.[TotalGoals]) AS Goals
          ,sum(P.[Total Assists])-sum(s.[TotalAssists]) AS Assists   
FROM [PredictionsPlayersHistory] as P   
JOIN [V_StatsPlayers] AS S on p.pLAYER_id = s.Player_id    
where S.LastPlayedDate >= '2010-02-01' and P.Player_id
    = 8471675   group by P.[Player_id],P.[PlayerName]   
order by Goals desc, Assists desc, GP asc
```

problem is the results arent right:

Predictions (SUM)

> PlayerName    GP  Goals   Assists
>
> Sidney Crosby 56  28  34

Actual data (SUM)

> PlayerName    GP  Goals   Assists
>
> Sidney Crosby 26  17  24

Results

> Sidney Crosby 28  -42 -98

Comment: You're grouping by `Id`, so you must have multiple predictions and results for each `Id`? If that's the case make sure you confirm that your expected result matches the 'prediction' and 'actual' are correct. If there's only one prediction then don't use 'group by' because it just confuses the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to join the two tables on the id column:

```
SELECT a.Id,a.Name, a.GP - p.GP AS DeltaGP, a.G - p.G AS DeltaG,  a.A - p.A AS DeltaA
FROM dbo.table1 AS a --actual values
JOIN dbo.table2 AS p --predictions
ON a.Id = p.Id;
```

For an introduction to SQL Server Joins check out my post series here: http://sqlity.net/en/1146/a-join-a-day-introduction/

---

EDIT: If you have multiple rows per player in each table you need to aggregate them before you join:

```
SELECT  a.Id,
        a.Name,
        a.GP - p.GP AS DeltaGP,
        a.G - p.G AS DeltaG,
        a.A - p.A AS DeltaA
FROM    (
          SELECT  Id,
                  Name,
                  SUM(GP) AS GP,
                  SUM(G) AS G,
                  SUM(A) AS A
          FROM    dbo.table1
          GROUP BY Id,
                  Name
        ) AS a --actual values
JOIN    (
          SELECT  Id,
                  SUM(GP) AS GP,
                  SUM(G) AS G,
                  SUM(A) AS A
          FROM    dbo.table2
          GROUP BY Id
        ) AS p
        --predictions
  ON a.Id = p.Id;
```

Depending on you requirements you might want to use AVG instead of SUM.

Answer (score 0):

Can you join tables by ID? If i got it right then:

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.name,
       (table1.gp - table2.gp) as DeltaGP,
       (table1.g - table2.g) as DeltaG,
       (table1.a - table2.a) as DeltaA
FROM table1
JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
```